# What's the correct way to use user local python environment under PEP668?

Tags: python

I have tried to install any python packages on Ubuntu 24.04, but found I cannot do that as in 22.04

[PEP668](https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/) said it is for avoiding package conflict between system-wide package and user installed package.

example:

```
$ pip install setuptools --user
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.11/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
```

But if I do that with `pipx`:

```bash
$ pipx install setuptools 

No apps associated with package pip or its dependencies. If you are attempting to install a library, pipx should not be used. Consider using pip or a similar tool instead.
```

I am really confused with current rules and can not install any package to **user local env**.

How can I manage my user local environment now? And how can I use latest `pip` (not linux-distro version) and other packages by default for current user?

My Environment (dockerfile just for reproduce):

```
FROM ubuntu:24.04

# add python
RUN apt install -y python3-pip python3-venv python-is-python3 pipx

USER ubuntu
WORKDIR /app
```

I know I can use some env manage tools (pyenv) to do that, but is there any built-in method to bring my user local env back?

Answer (score 2):

You tried to follow the instructions for installing an *application*. You need to follow the instructions for installing a *package*:

```
If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
sure you have python3-full installed.
```

Use `python3 -m venv whateverpath` to create a virtual environment in the specified path, and `whateverpath/bin/python` and `whateverpath/bin/pip` to run that virtual environment's Python or to install packages in that virtual environment.

---

Alternatively, if you are *absolutely sure* you would rather take the risk of breaking your system than use a virtual environment, you can run `pip` with the `--break-system-packages` flag, as the `pip` output said. This will not be safe, even if you use `--user`.

Comment: So can we say that the `--user` option has been de facto deprecated?

Comment: @PaleNeutron: Eh... it's still usable with non-externally-managed Python environments. I think virtual environments have been taking over the role of `--user` for a while, though.

Comment: Is there really no simple way for creating a default user based python env?

Comment: What is the "default user"?  This is not a meaningful (OS) concept.  The point is that there is a system-wide Python, per-user Python packages, and virtual environments.

Comment: @StephenC I meant per user. As in, can't pip install default to installing per user without breaking the system, while say sudo pip install mean installing system wide?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @user2357112, creating a virtual environment is mandatory for any project requiring external packages.

Once you have pip3 and venv installed, go to your directory to create the *yourenv* environment:

```
$ python3 -m venv yourenv
$ . yourenv/bin/activate
```

Visually, you know you're in thanks to the modified prompt that begins with **(yourenv)**.
Don't forget to update pip within the virtual env, and you're good to go!
You can write pip instead of pip3 now.

```
(yourenv) $ pip install -U pip
(yourenv) $ pip install package1 package2
```

To exit *yourenv*, you have to write **deactivate** unlike to a pipenv environment where Ctrl+D is enough:

```
(yourenv) $ deactivate
$
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 2):

### Externally Managed Environments

One point I'd like to emphasize from the formal [PEP668](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/externally-managed-environments/#externally-managed-environments) specification

> It also standardizes an interpretation of the `sysconfig` schemes so that, if a Python-specific package manager is about to install a package in an interpreter-wide context, it can do so in a manner that will avoid conflicting with the external package manager and reduces the risk of breaking software shipped by the external package manager.

The intent here is to protect Ubuntu tooling written in python from breaking when you update or modify packages (eg update manager, system config printer, landscape client, etc)

Your local binary of python is symlinked to the system binary. See [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407029/435138) to understanding user package management

---

### Containers and/or Virtual Environments

> How can I manage my user local environment now?

I'll echo the previous answers here: you run your programs from within a virtual environment (a [thorough tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/); my preferred method is with miniconda)

Or, if you're more familiar with Docker then there are a number of [python version specific images](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/)

For example

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY ./app /app
```

---

### Test System

I'm not sure why you were installing all those python packages in your docker image -- I had to remove the RUN line to get my image to build

```bash
docker build -t ubuntu-test-sys .
docker run ubuntu-test-sys
docker ps
docker exec -it dcb3330497e9 sh

# python --version
Python 3.9.18

# python3 --version
Python 3.9.18

# ls -lah /usr/local/bin/ | grep python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 Dec 19 20:58 python -> python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   14 Dec 19 20:58 python-config -> python3-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Dec 19 20:58 python3 -> python3.9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Dec 19 20:58 python3-config -> python3.9-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  18K Dec 19 20:58 python3.9
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3.0K Dec 19 20:58 python3.9-config

# ls -lah /usr/bin/ | grep python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     24 Mar 13  2023 pdb3.11 -> ../lib/python3.11/pdb.py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     31 Apr  9  2023 py3versions -> ../share/python3/py3versions.py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     10 Apr  9  2023 python3 -> python3.11
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   6.6M Mar 13  2023 python3.11
```

#### Docker build error using your example image

```bash
 => ERROR [2/3] RUN apt install -y python3-pip python3-venv python-is-python3 pipx                                                   0.3s
------
 > [2/3] RUN apt install -y python3-pip python3-venv python-is-python3 pipx:
#0 0.205
#0 0.205 WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
#0 0.205
#0 0.208 Reading package lists...
#0 0.220 Building dependency tree...
#0 0.221 Reading state information...
#0 0.221 E: Unable to locate package python3-pip
#0 0.221 E: Unable to locate package python3-venv
#0 0.221 E: Unable to locate package python-is-python3
#0 0.221 E: Unable to locate package pipx
------
Dockerfile:4
--------------------
   2 |
   3 |     # add python
   4 | >>> RUN apt install -y python3-pip python3-venv python-is-python3 pipx
   5 |
   6 |     USER ubuntu
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt install -y python3-pip python3-venv python-is-python3 pipx" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```